# Change width of form semantic ui

Tags: html, forms, grid, semantic-ui

Hi I'm working on a project using semantic ui. I have a form, as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/5dyzpt77/

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="ui main container">
    <div class="ui form">
    <div class="one field">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="one field">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Address</label>
         <div class="three fields">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
           <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
           <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I don't want the form to be full width like it is, I'd like it to be 6 columns wide, but still centered, and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your form-div class `six wide column centered` and wrap it with div with class `ui grid`:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="ui main container">
    <div class="ui grid">
    <div class="ui form six wide column centered">
    <div class="one field">
      <div class="field">
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="one field">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Address</label>
         <div class="three fields">
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
           <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
           <div class="field">
            <input type="text">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz88gd2y/)

Read more about grid system [here](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of a field, you can simple put it in a division tag with class name as `<size> wide field`

example:

```
<form class = "ui form" action = "">
  <div class="three wide field">
    <input type = "text" name = "firstname">
  </div>
  <div class = "field">
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Click here for more details](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html)